# Переопределение operator+() в производном классе

Tags: наследование, c++

Как переопределить operator+ в производном классе?

```
class Base
{
private:
    int m_a;
public:
    Base(int a): m_a(a) { }
    Base operator+(const Base& rhs) { return Base(m_a + rhs.m_a); }
};
class A: public Base
{
private:
    int m_b;
public:
    A(int a, int b): Base(a), m_b(b) { }
    A operator+(const A& rhs) { ??? }
};
```

Comment: Переопределяемый метод должен быть виртуальным:

 class Base
 {
 private:
  int m_a;
 public:
  Base(int a): m_a(a) { }
  virtual ~Base() { }
  virtual Base operator+(const Base& rhs) { return Base(m_a + rhs.m_a); }
 };
 
 class A: public Base
 {
 private:
  int m_b;
 public:
  A(int a, int b): Base(a), m_b(b) { }
  virtual A operator+(const A& rhs) override { /* ... */ }
 };

Не забывайте про деструктор базового класса: он должен быть виртуальным, если планируется наследование.

Comment: Спасибо, но все - таки, мне не понятно как определить operator+() в А. 
И да, зачем тут override? У меня компилятор ругается.

Comment: Уточните, какое поведение вам нужно получить? Переопределение нужно, если вы собираетесь обращаться к соотв. методам через базовый класс.

Comment: Нужно сложить два экземпляра класса A. Их члены должны просуммироваться, т.е.: m_a + rhs.m_a и m_b + rhs.m_b. Но ведь нельзя сложить rhs.m_a, private же... Не хочется в protected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
class A: public Base
{
private:
    int m_b;
    A(Base base, int b): Base(base), m_b(b) { }

public:
    A(int a, int b): Base(a), m_b(b) { }
    A operator+(const A& rhs) { return A(Base::operator+(rhs), m_b + rhs.m_b); }
};
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/0ADTj1

Comment: Вы бы пояснили, что это уже не переопределение.

Comment: @Flammable: Я, честно говоря, не знаю, что имеется в виду под словом «переопределение»: override или overload. Ну и виртуальным делать `operator+` не стоит, т. к. `A` не должно уметь складываться с `Base`.

Comment: @VladD, переопределение подразумевает переопределение виртуального метода базового класса. В вашем примере кода нет переопределения (да и перегрузки тоже), о котором спрашивал автор (в условиях данной задачи о нем речи идти не может).

Comment: @Flammable: overload вроде бы есть: два метода с одинаковыми именами в базовом классе и его наследнике.

Если ТСу нужен override (то есть, виртуальное наследование), то так делать нельзя, так что в этом случае ответ был бы «нельзя». Для overload мой код вроде бы делает то, что нужно.

Comment: @VladD, да, действительно.